# How to join two table with a condition linked to a third table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 table

```
Table1 : ID, Description
Table2 : ID, FirstName, LastName
Table3 : FirstName, LastName, Flag
```

I want to left join table1 and table2 with a condition that is linked to a third table.

```
Result Table: ID, Description, FullName (FirstName + LastName) 
(Condition: only the names that have flag set to true in table3 can be used in the resultant table)
```

How do i accomplish the following?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Description, t2.FirstName + ' ' + t2.LastName as FullName
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.FirstName=t3.FirstName AND t2.LastName=t3.LastName
WHERE t3.Flag=1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.